# dropdown is not working in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have created one dropdown  by using rest API in angular JS.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="address" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 control-label">Country</label>
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1">
<select ng-model="selectCountry" class="selectpicker" ng-options="item.name for item in countryList">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

My controller

```
angular.module('myWebApp').controller('signInController',function ($scope){
alert("sign clicked" + $scope.selectCountry);
});
```

But my '$scope.selectCountry' is showing [object] [object]. Please help.

Comment: please give countryList array

Comment: I guessed, that you have some fields in array item. $scope.selectCountry is a one of these items. You should concretize, what do you want to see. For example: $scope.selectCountry.name

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your countryList array looks like but your ng-options most likely needs to be:

```
item.countryId as item.name for item in countryList
```

value / name / entry / array

So in your case, since you didn't specify the value, the value became the whole object.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: My mistake. It was resolved now. It should be $scope.selectCountry.name